# Reverse Proxy Apache DNS error

Tags: apache, proxy, dns, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

Upon setting up my test reverse proxy I have encountered this issue:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/36Rbx.png - Sorry can't post images yet...

Below is the apache configuartion.

```
<virtualhost *:80>

  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  ServerName localhost
  ProxyRequests off
  <proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
  </proxy >
  ProxyPass / http://192.168.16.103/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.16.103/
</VirtualHost >
```

Any have any idea's whats causing this, the redirect comes from a web application on an internal IIS server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out a reboot of the system solved the issue!